# Multistep forms in Rails using AJAX

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following Railscast #217 which shows how to build a multistep form out of partials.  I followed Ryan's directions and got my code to work but was wondering how to convert this so that Rails will use AJAX to load the partials?

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    session[:user_params] ||= {}
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    session[:user_params].deep_merge!(params[:user]) if params[:user]

    params.each do |key,value|
      session.deep_merge!(key=>value) if params[:user]
    end

    @user = User.new(session[:user_params])
    @user.current_step = session[:user_step]
    if params[:prev_button]
      @user.previous_step
    elsif @user.last_step?
      @user.save
    else
      @user.next_step
    end

    session[:user_step] = @user.current_step

    if @user.new_record?
      render :new
    else
      session[:user_step] = session[:user_params] = nil
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to Friends First!"
      redirect_to @user
    end
    ...
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_writer :current_step

  def current_step
    @current_step || steps.first
  end

  def steps
    %w[step1 step2 step3]
  end

  def next_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step) + 1]
  end

  def previous_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step) - 1]
  end

  def first_step?
    current_step == steps.first
  end

  def last_step?
    current_step == steps.last
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%# render @user.current_step, :f => f %>

  <div id="form"></div>

  <div class="center">
    <%= f.submit "Previous", class: "btn btn-primary", :name => "prev_button" unless @user.first_step?  %>
    <%= f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-primary", :name => "next_button" unless @user.last_step? %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary", :name => "submit_button" if @user.last_step? %>
  </div>


<% end %>
```

**EDIT**
I'm going to post one of my partials. Notice the `f` variable - I don't know how to pass that into my partial from the form using AJAX.

**_step1.html.erb**

```
<div class="offset1">
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>  
</div>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(@user.current_step)) %>');
```

This doesn't work, I need to pass `f` in somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your rails actions, you didn't handle AJAX requests, and didn't initiate them in your views ..

Using AJAX, you need the following in order:

1. proper request from client side.
2. proper handling at server side.
3. proper handling of server response at client side.

Here is a [simple ajax example](https://github.com/kschlarman/ajax), and here is a [pagination example](https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination) using AJAX

Good luck :-)

Comment: I checked out your simple ajax example @simo.  And that is exactly what I was trying to do. My only hangup is how to pass my form_for's `f` variable in `new.html.erb` into my partial, `_step1.html.erb` using AJAX.  See my EDIT above.

Comment: I think that your line is commented! <%# render @user.current_step, :f => f %> make sure it starts with <%= instead : )

Answer (score 1):

A really simple way to make it feel more ajaxy, is to use the [pjax-rails](https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails).

You will need to change almost next to nothing, only define the `pjax-container` div that will be reloaded. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

@mikglaz I also faced the same problem. The solution i found is recreating the form in your '.js.erb' file.
I found it from [here](https://railsforum.com/topic/839-retrieve-form-builder-object-on-ajax-callback/).